# How to draw an activity diagram for the entire system?

Tags: uml, software-design

I have drawn an activity diagram to depict my project. Please, could anyone tell whether it is correct or wrong?[image: The activity diagram]

Comment: this is not a valid diagram (may be I have to say in an answer ? ^^) what tool you used to make it ?

Comment: @bruno umm visio?

Comment: @bruno As far as I see it's valid UML. However, whether or not it describes the OP's system we can only guess since we don't know his system.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram has the following errors:

1. The start node should be a filled circle (you have an open circle).
2. The end node should have a filled inner circle, like a bull's eye.
3. If an action has more than one outgoing arrow, then this means that all outgoing paths are traversed *simultaneously*. In your case, you want only one path at a time. Use a decision symbol (diamond) in between Login and the subsequent actions.
4. All actions should have at least one outgoing arrow. This arrow should go back to the decision symbol you forgot to draw (see 3).
5. The two arrows to the end node mean that the activity ends if *both* paths have been traversed. In your case, you want the activity to end if *either* of the paths has been traversed. Use a merge symbol (diamond) for that.